# How to find out which Linux driver is hogging my GPIO

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio

I have a pad multiplxed as GPIO on my board. When I try to export it via /sys/class/gpio/export, I get

```
-sh: echo: write error: Device or resource busy
```

My guess is some other driver is requesting this pad before I get that chance. How can I find out what is reserving it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

On the Boundary Devices kernel, and maybe others, you can use `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio` to get a list of the mapped gpios, their states, and name given when it was allocated. You can grep the kernel source for the name and find out what module grabbed it.

```
root@nitrogen6x:/opt# cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio 
GPIOs 0-31, platform/209c000.gpio, 209c000.gpio:
 gpio-2   (flexcan-trx-stby    ) out lo    
 gpio-17  (DISP_SCL            ) out lo    

GPIOs 32-63, platform/20a0000.gpio, 20a0000.gpio:
 gpio-33  (sysfs               ) out lo    
 gpio-35  (sysfs               ) in  hi    
 gpio-36  (sysfs               ) in  hi    
 gpio-37  (DISP_SDI            ) out lo    
 gpio-38  (219c000.usdhc cd    ) in  hi    

GPIOs 64-95, platform/20a4000.gpio, 20a4000.gpio:
 gpio-83  (spi_imx             ) out lo    
 gpio-86  (usb_otg_vbus        ) out lo    

GPIOs 96-127, platform/20a8000.gpio, 20a8000.gpio:
 gpio-101 (sysfs               ) in  hi    
 gpio-116 (rst-gpios           ) out lo    

GPIOs 128-159, platform/20ac000.gpio, 20ac000.gpio:

GPIOs 160-191, platform/20b0000.gpio, 20b0000.gpio:
 gpio-175 (wlan-en             ) out lo    
 gpio-176 (bt_rfkill_reset     ) out lo    

GPIOs 192-223, platform/20b4000.gpio, 20b4000.gpio:
 gpio-192 (2198000.usdhc cd    ) in  lo    
 gpio-204 (ehci_reset_gpio     ) out lo    
 gpio-205 (sysfs               ) in  lo
```

'

Comment: Thank you, this looks immensely useful. I wonder if it existed 3 years ago.

Comment: Probably. I searched for the same question, and didn't find an answer, so I just did a `find /sys -name gpio` and found this, which let me know that I was requesting the wrong GPIO.

Answer (score 7):

if you try to use `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio` and it is not working, first try:

```
mount -t debugfs debugfs /sys/kernel/debug
```

and then use the aforementioned `cat` command

Answer (score 5):

`/sys/kernel/debug/gpio` is part of the [Legacy GPIO Interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/driver-api/gpio/legacy.html) and may not be present on newer kernels. A replacement is the `gpioinfo` tool of [libgpio-tools](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git/tree/README); these tools use the newer [character device interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/driver-api/gpio/driver.html) for handling gpios.

If using [buildroot](https://buildroot.org), enable `BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGPIOD` and `BR2_PACKAGE_LIBGPIOD_TOOLS`.

```
buildroot:~ $ gpiodetect
gpiochip0 [30200000.gpio] (32 lines)
gpiochip1 [30210000.gpio] (32 lines)
gpiochip2 [30220000.gpio] (32 lines)
gpiochip3 [30230000.gpio] (32 lines)
gpiochip4 [30240000.gpio] (32 lines)
gpiochip5 [0-0023] (16 lines)

buildroot:~ $ gpioinfo
gpiochip0 - 32 lines:
    line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   1:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   2:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   3:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   4:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   5:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   6:      unnamed "pci_usb_sel" output active-high [used]
    line   7:      unnamed       "dio0"   input  active-high [used]
    line   8:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high 
    line   9:      unnamed       "dio1"   input  active-high [used]
    line  10:      unnamed "regulator-usb-otg1" output active-high [used]
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'lsof' command to list the open files. according to fact that gpio files are regular files. (e.g /sys/class/gpio/gpio242/value).
Also you should be sure of loading the right kernel modules (with insmod or modprobe) into memory.

Comment: That will not work as the sysfs node does not exist yet. Echoing the GPIO number to export should create the node, but it does not.

Comment: If you load the right kernel module, you can see all of available gpio in /sys/devices/virtual/gpio/ directory.
Whats your contents of directory?
You can see the label file to follow its real position in schematics of board.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using another GPIO pin. i.mx6 has 7 GPIO controllers with 32 pins each, and some conrollers were simply giving I/O errors out of seemingly nowhere.